# Can any tell me the regular expression for the given language?

Tags: automation, compiler-construction, automata

all strings which contains **even number of 0s or even number of 1s**.  Here I am asking about 'or' not 'and'.

I have come up with this: **(1*01*0)*|(0*10*1)*** so far...but this seems wrong to me cause when you draw DFA for the above language you can even accept 111 or 000 too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For zeros, allow for any number of pars of zeros with any number of leading non-zeros and separating non-zeros. **And then allow for any trailing non-zeros.** If the string does not match this pattern, it has an odd number of zeros.

```
(1*01*0)*1*
```

And to do it for zeros or ones, just copy with `1`s instead and add it as an alternative to the whole thing.

```
(1*01*0)*1*|(0*10*1)*0*
```

Also, `111` and `000` both correctly satisfy the condition, because `111` has an even number of `0`s and `000` has an even number of `1`s.  Examples that shouldn't work would be `1101` or `011100`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it. Appreciated!